# One-to-many audio CD duplication software (Windows 10/XP, Linux)

Tags: linux, windows

Does anyone know of software that either:

- Allows me to replace a hardware cd duplicator. (The kind where you put in a master cd, push one button, and it will write the contents of the master cd to multiple slave drives)
- Allows me to burn one set of audio files to as many burner drives as I have hooked up to my computer.

I have looked into all sorts of software but everything I have found doesn't meet these criteria because either:

- it is focused on creating audio CD's from individual files but doesn't have an easy functionality for selecting multiple target drives
- it is solely focused on creating and burning ISO files (which due to time constraints of our workflow, I need to cut out this intermediary step)

If a hardware duplicator is the way to go in terms of cost-time invested in this, then I'll just go that route. But I was hoping someone may have run into this situation before and knew of some purpose-built software that will turn a computer with a bunch of drives into a duplicator.

Note: This could be done on either a Windows 10 pc or an older computer we have laying around that has XP but I could load Linux onto. So I'm flexible with OS requirements.

Comment: http://www.deepburner.com/?r=products&pr=deepburner&prr=features